# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() PHP MySQL private message system

Tags: php, mysql, function, foreach, arguments

I am new to this forum and also new to PHP and MySQL.  I get the following error when I open a page called view_conversation.page.inc.php:

```
    <?php

$errors = array();
$valid_conversation = (isset($_GET['conversation_id']) && validate_conversation_id($_GET['conversation_id']));
if ($valid_conversation === false){
        $errors[] = 'Invalid Conversation ID.';
}
if (isset($_POST['message'])){
        if (empty($_POST['message'])){
                $errors[] = 'You must enter a message.';
        }

        if (empty($errors)){
                add_conversation_message($_GET['conversation_id'], $_POST['message']);
        }
}

if (empty($errors) === false){
        foreach ($errors as $error){
        }
}
echo $error;

if ($valid_conversation){
        /*if (isset($_POST['message'])){
                update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);*/
                $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
                print_r($messages);
        /*}else{
                $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
                update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);
        }*/

}
?>
<a href="index.php?page=inbox">Inbox</a>
<a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>

        <form action="" method="post">
                <p><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="110"></textarea></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Add Message" /></p>
        </form>

        <?php
        foreach ($messages as $message){
        ?>
        <?php if ($message['unread']) echo 'unread'; ?>
        <p class="name">Username: <?php echo $message['user_name']; ?></p>
        <p class="text">Date: <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $message['date']); ?></p>
        <p>Message: <?php echo $message['text']; ?></p>

<?php

}
?>
```

It links to functions in the page named private_message.inc.php:

```
    <?php

    // Fetches a summary of the conversations.
    function fetch_conversation_summary(){
            $sql = "SELECT
                                    `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
                                    `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
                                    MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`,
                                    MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
                            FROM `conversations`
                            LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON  `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                            WHERE `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                            AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
                            GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
                            ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            $conversations = array();

            while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
                    $conversations[] = array(
                            'id'                            => $row['conversation_id'],
                            'subject'                       => $row['conversation_subject'],
                            'last_reply'            => $row['conversation_last_reply'],
                            'unread_messages'       => ($row['conversation_unread'] == 1),
                    );
            }

            return $conversations;
    }

// Fetches all of the messages in the given converstion.
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

        $sql = "SELECT
                                `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                                `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                                `conversations_message`.`message_text`,
                                `users`.`user_name`
                        FROM `conversations_messages`
                        INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
                        INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
                        WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                        AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                        ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $messages = array();

        while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
                $messages[] = array(
                        'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                        'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                        'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                        'user_name' => $row['user_name'],
                );
        }

        return $messages;
}

/*function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

        $sql = "SELECT
            `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
            `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
            `users`.`user_name`
        FROM `conversations_messages`
        INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
        WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
        ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        var_dump($result);
        $messages = array();

        while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
                $messages[] = array(
                        'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                        'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                        'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                        'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
                );
                        var_dump($row);

        }
echo count($messages);}*/


    // Sets the last view time to the current time for the given conversation.
    function update_conversation_last_view($conversation_id){
            $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;
            $time = time() + 18000;
            $sql ="UPDATE `conversations_members`
                            SET `conversation_last_view` = {$time}
                            WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                            AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

            mysql_query($sql);     
    }

     // Creates a new conversation, making the given users a member.
    function create_conversation($user_ids, $subject, $body){
            $subject        = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($subject));
            $body           = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($body));

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `conversations` (`conversation_subject`) VALUES ('{$subject}')");

            $conversation_id = mysql_insert_id();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
                            VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$body}')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");

            foreach ($user_ids as $user_id){
                    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

        $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_members` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `conversation_last_view`, `conversation_deleted`)
                            VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);

                            mysql_query($sql);
    }


    // Checks to see if the given user is a member of the given conversation.

   function validate_conversation_id($conversation_id){
   $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM `conversations_members`
   WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
   AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
   AND `conversation_deleted` = 0";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   return(mysql_result($result, 0) == 1);
   }
    // Adds a message to the given conversation.
    function add_conversation_message($conversation_id, $text){
            $conversation_id        = (int)$conversation_id;
            $text                   = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`,     `message_date`, `message_text`)
                            VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$text}')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            mysql_query("UPDATE `conversations_members` SET `conversation_deleted` = 0 where `conversation_id = {$conversation_id}");
    }

// Deletes (or marks as deleted) a given conversation.
function delete_conversation($conversation_id){
            $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `conversation_deleted`
                            FROM `conversations_members`
                            WHERE `user_id` != {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                            AND `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 && mysql_result($result, 0) == 1){
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_members` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_messages` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
            }else{
                    $sql = "UPDATE `conversations_members`
                                    SET `conversation_deleted` = 1
                                    WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                                    AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

                    mysql_query($sql);

            }
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Your code has multiple `foreach`'s. Which line is the warning referring to?

Comment: line 45 (46 with the proposed if statement)

Answer (score 0):

That means that you are trying to loop through an array using `foreach`, but either the array does not have anything in it, or you are trying to loop through something that is not an array (like a string).  The PHP error should give you a line number so that you can see where the `foreach` is being called.

Comment: yes, it is line 45.  Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Okay, so line 45 is `foreach ($messages as $message){`, which means that it is not able to loop through the variable `$messages`.  On line 27, you are setting `$messages`, but ONLY `if ($valid_conversation){`.  You should put in an `else` to say if the `$valid_conversation` does not evaluate, then set `$messages` to an empty array.  `$messages = array();`

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same output of Array ( ) 1 with the foreach error below

Comment: Okay, then do what Alireza Fallah has suggested in his answer.  You should check to see if the thing you are trying to loop through is set before trying to loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

This warning error means that you are trying to loop through a ***non-array variable***, or an ***empty array*** .

for solving it, put an ***`if`*** before your foreach, 
like this :

```
$messages = ...
if($messages){
   foreach($messages as $message){
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: An empty array would not cause the warning nor is it true that all non-arrays will cause the warning (it must be an array or an instance of Traversable).

Comment: I tried that (probably implemented it incorrectly though) with an if(isset($messages){ statement, but again, the error remained the same

Comment: can you give me an example with the variables - I did not even know what mysql was until 2 weeks ago!

Comment: dont use `isset`, try like what I said in  my answer

Comment: or how to start a php tag

Comment: `if ($messages) {
foreach ($messages as $message){`

Comment: foreach ($messages as $message){
            ?>
            <?php if ($message['unread']) echo 'unread'; ?>
            <p class="name">Username: <?php echo $message['user_name']; ?></p>
            <p class="text">Date: <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $message['date']); ?></p>
            <p>Message: <?php echo $message['text']; ?></p>
     
    <?php
     
    }}

Comment: look at the update, you are missing ***`if`***, again

Comment: sorry,    if($messages){ comes before all that code, I just forgot to copy it\

Comment: does anyone know what is wrong with this code?  It may also be one of the two functions from private_message.inc.php that was declared